# Performance testing Open vStorage and Ceph using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, ceph

I have a query regarding benchmarking the performance of Open vStorage (storage platform) using Apache JMeter. Is it possible to run tests against Open vstorage using JMeter ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to your question is probably "yes", but it might be "no". How would either of these answers be useful to you. Please read the [help] documentation on what sort of questions are on topic here and on how to write a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wanted to know if JMeter could be used as the tool for benchmarking Open vStorage or should i go with any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the protocols of this Open vStorage.

If it's one supported by JMeter then yes:

- Web
- HTTP/HTTPS
- SOAP
- Database via JDBC
- MongoDB (to be removed)
- LDAP
- JMS Mail
- SMTP(S), POP3(S) and IMAP(S)
- Native commands or shell scripts

If it's not but it has a Java API, then you can plug it using either:

- JSR223 + Groovy and coding the call in Groovy
- or using [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)  and coding a [JavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerClient.html)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to test but I assume you want to test the storage performance of Open vStorage compared to Ceph RDB? Typically one uses tools like fio (http://linux.die.net/man/1/fio) to test storage performance. I had a quick look at the JMeter and it doesn't provide a storage benchmark option.